# R language Amelia specify prefix of output files

Tags: r, filenames, imputation

This R statement uses the Amelia package to create output data files containing imputed data:

`ds.im <- amelia(ds, m=5, p2s=2)`

The names of the 5 output files are: output1.csv to output5.csv

In the Amelia package, is there a way to specify the prefix of the output files to something more meaningful? For example, boat_impute1.csv to boat_impute5.csv

I could not locate such a command in the amelia documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Amelia/vignettes/amelia.pdf)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My question not a good one.

The output files are not written with the amelia command. Rather they are written with the 
write.amelia command. One enters what I called the prefix with the file.stem command, such as:

```
write.amelia(ds.im, file.stem = "boat_impute", format = "csv")
```